# Vale a pena iniciar projetos de médio e grande porte com angular 2?

Tags: angular

como está a experiência com o uso do angular 2 para projetos um pouco maiores?

Algum ponto negativo ou positivo encontrado em relação ao seu uso?

Quero fazer um balanço se vale a pena mudar para ele.

Comment: Uma leitura interessante para a sua dúvida é [Angular 2: Vale a pena migrar agora?](http://blog.algaworks.com/migrar-para-angular-2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a parte principal de um projeto é sua API. Criando uma API consistente para back-end, a escolha do front-end fica mais fácil.

Em um projeto solo que estou trabalhando, estou desenvolvendo a back-end API em Node+MongoDB+Express e pretendo fazer o front-end com Angular 2, ou seja, o famoso MEAN => Mongo+Express+Angular+Node .